# Combining queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following tables:

```
    schools
    --------
id  |   school_name 
1           harvy
2           iltes

    school_tags
        -----------
id  |   tag_id      |   school_id
i       abc             1
2       def             2
```

I have following tables i want to delete schools id = 2. But it has foreign key in school_tags. I can delete it using single queries like:

```
delete from school_tags where school_id = 2;
```

then

```
delete from schools where id = 2;
```

Is there an easy way to combine these queries?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - mysql

Comment: @NoviceMe I've just added `mysql` as a tag - you should do this in the future yourself (instead of adding crucial information as a comment only)!

Comment: @NoviceMe why not use `OR`?

Answer (score 0):

You should define your school_tags table with the ON DELETE CASCADE clausule.

So, when the parent school is deleted, all of it's childrens are also deleted.

[Check it out.](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/)

Comment: I already have table with data in it. Is there a way to add DELETE CASCADE now?

Comment: Yo must remove the Foreign Key first: ALTER TABLE school_tags DROP FOREIGN KEY `school_id` and then ALTER TABLE school_tags
   ADD CONSTRAINT `school_id`
   FOREIGN KEY (`school_id` )
   REFERENCES `schools` (`school_id` )
   ON DELETE CASCADE. Try it first on a testing enviroment! I am not sure if I write it right or if it will make you loose some data. Test it first.